# LWC - Local Dev - How can I run the local server on HTTPS?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was trying to use local development in lwc (lightning web components) but I found that I can't access the org data because of cors. I try to add my local URL (http:0.0.0.0:3001) that lwc services generate for me when I run (npm start watch). But my org does not accept http url, only https, so the question is, how can I start my local server on https so I can add my URL to my Whitelisted Origins on my org?
Thank you!

Comment: How to setup this local development? Is there any documentation related to his? @sebas

Comment: @ajinkyah Hi! Here it is all the doc: https://lwc.dev/

Comment: This website is for LWC Open Source, right? Is this the same as Local Development for LWC which was presented in TrailheadDX?

Comment: @ajinkyah that's right!

Comment: Ohh. I don't think it is the same. Local Development for LWC allows us to locally preview components from a SFDX project whereas Open Source is not connected to any Salesforce Org.

Comment: @ajinkyah exactly, this is for that. Also to use lwc with amazon for example.

Comment: I think there's still some confusion. @ajinkyah I think you might want to check this video out that demonstrates using local development separate from the open source components.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nygnbZj4EXs

Comment: Right Joe. I have seen this. Local development will be supported with a sfdx command and is intended for local development of the components for Salesforce org which is not the case with LWC open source. People are mixing these two and considering the two to be same.

Comment: @JoeFlowers do you know if the local dev for salesforce lwc is available yet? I tried but have not found anything (only the video preview...)

Comment: @RadekMichna I don't believe it's available yet

Comment: And now we have a beta! https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can whitelist http://localhost:3001 - localhost is an allowed exception

Comment: For anyone that try this solution, when you start the server with 'npm run watch' the url it is 0.0.0.0 but you can also use localhost, it works. Thanks @Renji-xD

Answer (score 1):

When you want to launch `watch` mode with HTTPS you can pass a custom `webpack.config.js` using the `-w` flag that will enable the [https option in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps).